# Привязка домена к ВМ серверу

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

Не могу нигде найти инфу, как настроить сам сервер.
У меня есть сервер, на сервере крутится докер образ, а именно образ с сервисом на базе ангуляра, на порту 4200.
Подключиться по ип и порту из вне к сервису могу, благо к докер образу проброшены порты 4200:4200.
Я прикрутил домен к серверу, но домен стучиться только к порту 80, пытаюсь пробросить до порта 4200, выводит ошибку nginx error!. Если стучусь так http://site.info:4200, то всё ок! Как мне сделать, что бы при обращении по домему site.info меня форвартнуло на сервис, который запущен на порту 4200.
Что сейчас я имею:
/etc/ngnix/nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name site.info www.site.info;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4200;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}}
```

Comment: Нашёл решение вот в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx/24830777#24830777

Answer (score 0):

Я не сильно знаком с докером, но для начала нужно с сервера с порта `80` и `443` пробросить на `4200` и потом уже смотреть на настройки `nginx`, скорее всего, там необходимо будет прописать не `80` а `4200` так как туда приходит трафик

Answer (score 0):

Читайте ваш конфиг, там же написано

```
listen       80;
listen       [::]:80;
```

"слушаю порт 80", а вы к серверу обращаетесь по порту 4200 (  http://site.info:4200 ), который nginx не слушает.

Comment: listen       80;  это настройка на поднятия нгх сервера на порту 80.

Comment: @Connect1507 это значит слушать порт 80. Тот самый порт, с которым http работает по умолчанию. Добавьте строчку в общем listen       4200; , и по крайней мере nginx обработает ваш запрос . Да и кстати ещё надо разблокировать порт 4200 в фаерволе, чтобы запрос для начала дошёл до linux